# Parameter order evaluation

Tags: c++, parameters, operator-precedence

In previous versions of the standard (C++03) the order of evaluation of parameters to a function call was unspecified.

Has this been changed in subsequent version of the standard (C++11 or C++14)?
i.e. Can we rely on a specific ordering (left to right) or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this has not changed but there is a very recent proposal to change this: [N4228: Refining Expression Evaluation Order for
Idiomatic C++](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4228.pdf), this was part of the [Pre-Urbana mailing that came out this October](http://isocpp.org/blog/2014/10/pre-urbana) The introduction says  (*emphasis mine going forward*):

> Expression evaluation order is a recurring discussion topic in the
>   C++ community. In a nutshell, **given an expression such as f(a, b, c),
>   the order in which the sub-expressions f , a , b , c are evaluated
>   is left unspecified by the standard.** If any two of these
>   sub-expressions happen to modify the same object without intervening
>   sequence points, the behavior of the program is undefined. For
>   instance, the expression f(i++, i) where i is an integer variable
>   leads to undefined behavior

it proposes:

> We propose to revise C++ evaluation rules to support decades-old
>   idiomatic constructs and programming practices. A simple solution
>   would be to require that every expression has a well-defined
>   evaluation order. That suggestion has traditionally met resistance for
>   various reasons. Rather, this proposes suggests a more targeted fix
>
> - Postfix expressions are evaluated from left to right. **This includes
>     functions calls and member section expressions**.
> - Assignment expressions are evaluated from right to left. This includes compound assignments.
> - Operands to shift operators are evaluated from left to right

**Update**

Herb Sutter recently [put out a poll on order of evaluation](http://herbsutter.com/2014/12/01/a-quick-poll-about-order-of-evaluation/?utm_source=tf&utm_medium=t) looking for some feedback from the community on what result we would expect from the following code:

```
std::vector<int> v = { 0, 0 };
int i = 0;
v[i++] = i++;
std::cout << v[0] << v[1] << endl;
```

This would seem to indicate the committee is looking at the topic of order of evaluation seriously but as we can see from the discussion this is controversial.

Comment: Is this targeted at the upcoming C++17 or is still under heavy discussion?

Comment: @LokiAstari I am unfortunately not part of the committee so my insight is pretty limited, I had read this paper soon after the mailing came out, which is why I was able to answer so quickly. This is not related to a defect report so it seems like it would have to be part of C++17 assuming the discussions are in favor of this proposal. From what have read in the past and various conversations from cppcon this seems like a controversial proposal.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Unless the attitudes in the committee have changed considerably, the proposal has probably been dismissed.

Comment: @JamesKanze I agree it will be controversial but considering it is targetting a small set of expressions so perhaps that approach may reduce the resistance.

Answer (score 0):

No it is still unspecified in C++11. This is so your compilers can do micro optimizations that would improve the quality of the code, and is varied from compiler to compiler. Try printf with increment operations on different compilers.

functions like int i = foo(3) + bar(0); has undefined behaviors, no function is guaranteed to operate first.

Comment: Thanks. But I am well aware of the reasons for it being unspecified. But I had heard that it was under review but was unsure if the change had made it into the most recent standard.

Comment: @LokiAstari you might want to add the detail that you heard it was under review to your question. I assumed this is why you asked but it may not be obvious to others.