# How to properly forward unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, unique-ptr

What is generally the proper way to forward an std::unique_ptr?

The following code uses `std::move`, which I thought was the considered practice, but it crashes with clang.

```
class C {
   int x;
}

unique_ptr<C> transform1(unique_ptr<C> p) {
    return transform2(move(p), p->x); // <--- Oops! could access p after move construction takes place, compiler-dependant
}

unique_ptr<C> transform2(unique_ptr<C> p, int val) {
    p->x *= val;
    return p;
}
```

Is there a more robust convention than simply making sure you get everything you need from `p` before transferring ownership to the next function via `std::move`? It seems to me using `move` on an object and accessing it to provide a parameter to the same function call could be a common mistake to make.

Comment: Have you ever considered using raw pointers? It's these situations where so-called 'smart pointers' are extremely impractical for use.

Comment: This code definitely shouldn’t crash, at least not for the reason you mention — `std::move` doesn’t actually perform a move, and `p->x` does *not* access `p` after the move.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: It could still fail. The initialization of the parameter to `transform2` *will* perform move construction. At which point, `p` in `transform1` is empty. Remember: compilers can re-order these expressions any way they see fit.

Comment: @NicolBolas Expression reordering alone cannot cause the crash because, as mentioned, the expression `std::move(p)` does nothing, it just changes the static type of the expression. That said, you might be right because I don’t know at what exact time point parameter initialisation happens; I *thought* it happened after all parameter expressions were evaluated, but I have no idea.

Comment: Why pass `p->x` separately when you're passing the whole object anyway?

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Presumably, `transform2` could be used with a value other than `p->x`; `transform2` is general purpose multiplication, `transform1` is a specialization that squares.

Comment: @KonradRudolph you are right, order of evaluation is not specified in the standard, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934904/order-of-evaluation-in-c-function-parameters thus using move at any point of the program will cause any use of that object later on to activate UB.

Comment: If you are not transferring ownership, you should not be passing a smart pointer. Anyway, Nicol Bolas nailed it.

Comment: @user1708860 I am actually saying the exact opposite: the mere use of `std::move` does *not* cause later uses of that object to be UB. On the contrary, the following code is completely fine according to the standard: `auto&& q = std::move(p); p->x;`. You have a misconception about what `std::move` does.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, after looking it up, i see what you mean. The code is indeed fine, as is - it will not activate UB. If i understand correctly it will activate unspecified behavior, which will not cause a crash, but it is not promised to give a correct result.

Comment: @user1708860 The code I’ve shown in my comment is well-defined: it gives neither undefined nor unspecified behaviour, and it always gives the correct result, guaranteed. However, as for the code in OP’s case: see Nicol’s comment above (and my reply to that).

Comment: @KonradRudolph can you quote the standard or some other resource?

Comment: @user1708860 http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move is sufficient — look at the section “Return value” in particular. That’s all `std::move` does!

Comment: What would be nice is a compiler that warns about possible use of moved-from objects, in the same way as for uninitialized variables.

Comment: The comment in the code in the question is a bit misleading. The issue is that you could access `p` after the move construction of the function parameter takes place.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Improved comment, thanks

Comment: @NicolBolas Are the expressions fully evaluated before any parameter initialization occurs, or can the expressions *and parameter initialization* be reordered?  I suspect initialization can be reordered relative to each other and the expressions, but Konrad's point is that expression reordering is insufficient, I think.

Comment: @Yakk: "*can the expressions and parameter initialization be reordered*" I don't know. Generally speaking, when esoteric rules like reording are involved, I err on the side of caution.

Answer (score 5):

Since you do not really need to access `p` after it was moved, one way would be to get `p->x` before the move and then use it.

Example:

```
unique_ptr<C> transform1(unique_ptr<C> p) {
    int x = p->x;
    return transform2(move(p), x);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but the question is "Is there a *more robust convention* than simply making sure you get everything you need from p before transferring ownership to the next function via std::move", which is what you suggest. The idea is to prevent this bug in general.

Comment: @Danra, but you can't. You can not use contents of the pointer after it was moved, and (as outlined in the comments) if you use `std::move` in the function calling context it is undefined when the object will be moved. In a single-threaded program you can get a raw pointer and use it in the function arguments, though. Is this what you are looking to get?

Comment: No, I'm looking for a way which could prevent this seemingly (to me at least) easy bug to make. e.g. Some sort of move-like operation but which would only invalidate the object after it goes out of scope (and before its destructor is called)

Comment: But that's just an example, I'm open to any other robust solution, if one exists

Comment: @Danra, this is not unique_ptr does! It invalidates the object right after the move, because it is very rationale for it's existance. If the object would be invalidated only when it goes out of scope, you would end up with more than one owner (the one which is still in-scope, and the one you've just passed it to). What you are saying seems to be use-case for shared_ptr, not unique_ptr.

Comment: @Danra if you are looking for a dummy proof way of doing this, you should look for something more like David Haim's answer and remove the ownership logic.

Comment: @user1708860, i totally disagree with what David is saying. He is effectively advocating agains move semantics at all.

Comment: @SergeyA Not really, shared_ptr offers more semantics such as copying which increments its counter. The requirement of staying 'alive' until going out of scope is a weaker one than what shared_ptr provides.

Comment: @user1708860 This is a simplified example. Assume move semantics are indeed required. The problem presented is a general one.

Answer (score 4):

The code is **not** fine.

- std::move is nothing but a cast (g++: something like
  `static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&>(value)`)
- Value computation and side effects of each argument expression are
  sequenced before execution of the called function.
- **However**, the initialization of function parameters takes place in the
  context of the calling function. (Thanks to [T.C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c))

Quotes from the draft N4296:

1.9/15 Program execution

> [...] When calling a function (whether or not the function is inline), every
>   value computation and side effect associated with any argument
>   expression, or with the postfix expression designating the called
>   function, is sequenced before execution of every expression or
>   statement in the body of the called function. [...]

5.2.2/4 Function call

> When a function is called, each parameter (8.3.5) shall be initialized
>   (8.5, 12.8, 12.1) with its corresponding argument. [ Note: Such
>   initializations are indeterminately sequenced with respect to each
>   other (1.9) end note ] [...] The initialization and destruction of each
>   parameter occurs within the context of the calling function. [...]

A sample (g++ 4.8.4):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
struct X
{
    int x = 1;
    X() {}
    X(const X&) = delete;
    X(X&&) {}
    X& operator = (const X&) = delete;
    X& operator = (X&&) = delete;
};


void f(std::shared_ptr<X> a, X* ap, X* bp, std::shared_ptr<X> b){
    std::cout << a->x << ", " << ap << ", " << bp << ", " << b->x << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    auto a = std::make_unique<X>();
    auto b = std::make_unique<X>();
    f(std::move(a), a.get(), b.get(), std::move(b));
}
```

The output may be `1, 0xb0f010, 0, 2`, showing a (zero) pointer moved away.

Comment: "initialization of function parameters" is not a "expression or statement in the body of the called function". In fact, your own quote says that it "occurs within the context of the calling function", not the called function.

Comment: Note the possible output should read `1, 0xb0f010, 0, 1`, to match the edited code. You can't make edits of 1 character so this comment serves as a sanity check to anyone reading.

Answer (score 3):

Stop doing more than one thing on a single line, unless the operations are non-mutating.

Code isn't faster if it is all on one line, and it is often less correct.

`std::move` is a mutating operation (or more accurately, it flags an operation to follow as "mutate ok").  It should be on its own line, or at the least it should be on a line with no other interaction with its parameter.

This is like `foo( i++, i )`.  You modified something and also used it.

If you want a universal brainless habit, simply bind all arguments in `std::forward_as_tuple`, and call `std::apply` to call the function.

```
unique_ptr<C> transform1(unique_ptr<C> p) {
  return std::experimental::apply( transform2, std::forward_as_tuple( std::move(p), p->x ) );
}
```

which avoids the problem because the mutation of `p` is done on a line different than the reading of the `p.get()` address in `p->x`.

Or, roll your own:

```
template<class F, class...Args>
auto call( F&& f, Args&&...args )
->std::result_of_t<F(Args...)>
{
  return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>)...);
}
unique_ptr<C> transform1(unique_ptr<C> p) {
  return call( transform2, std::move(p), p->x );
}
```

The goal here is to order the evaluation-of-parameter expressions separately from the evaluation-of-parameter-initialization.  It still doesn't fix some move-based issues (like SSO `std::basic_string` move-guts and reference-to-char issues).

Next to that, hope that a compiler will add warnings for unordered mutate-and-read in the general case.

Comment: The first solution seems a bit naive to me; rvalue-reference parameters are widespread since c++11, and as soon as you chain more than one such function passing a parameter through the chain, you are at risk of getting the above bug, and it *looks* fine to just one-line the entire forwarding to the next function in the chain, including the move. The second solution is nice but not something easily accessible to everyone, to prevent them from tripping over the potential bug.

Comment: @Danra Forwarding, without accessing data, is as safe as the caller was: if they didn't flag a mutation at the same time as a read, you should be fine.  Forwarding, with additional data access, requires scrutiny that the thing you are forwarding isn't the thing you are reading elsewhere (as a forward is a possible move)?  Can you construct an explicit counter example?

Comment: Explicit counter example to what? Not sure I gotcha.

Comment: @Danra My claim is that forwarding won't introduce such errors, because the error will have occurred at the point where the forwarding was *started*.  On the other hand, you said that chained forwards somehow increase the risk of the above bug.  Is there an example where this happens deep in a chain, but not obviously at the interface where the move was done?

Comment: First two sentences "Stop doing more than one thing on a single line, unless the operations are non-mutating.

Code isn't faster if it is all on one line, and it is often less correct." of this answer are really the crux of the issue imo. The other answers are beating around the bush.

Comment: @Yakk I just meant that the offending function (transform1 in my example) might itself have gotten its parameter through a move constructor, and this could become more common as forwarding becomes more commonplace in code: it's reasonable there will be a few functions in a chain forwarding parameters one to the next, with one of the functions in the middle doing a mistake such as in transform1.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in [Dieter Lücking's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35043929/166389), the value computations are sequenced before function body, so the `std::move` and `operator ->` are sequenced before the body of the function --- 1.9/15.

However, this does *not* specify that the parameter initialization is done after all of those computations, they can appear anywhere with regard to each other, and to non-dependent value computations, as long as they are done before the function body --- 5.2.2/4.

This means the behaviour is undefined here, as one expression modifies p (moving into a temporary argument) and the other uses the value of p, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26911480/166389. Although as mentioned there, [P0145](http://wg21.link/p0145) proposes to fix the evaluation order to left-to-right (in this case). Which would mean your code is broken, but `transform2(p->x, move(p))` would do what you want. (Corrected, thanks to [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c))

As far as idioms go to avoid this, consider [David Haim's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35042884/166389) taking the `unique_ptr<C>` by reference, although that's pretty opaque to the caller. You're signalling something like "May modify this pointer". `unique_ptr`'s moved-from state is reasonably clear, so this isn't likely to bite you as badly as if you move from a passed-in object reference or something.

In the end, you need a sequence point between using `p` and modifying `p`.

Comment: Actually, P0145 would fix this to do left-to-right.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, no, there isn't a fool-proof method of doing this without taking care of the small details. Where it gets really sneaky is in member-initialization-lists.

Just an as example that goes one step beyond yours, what happens if `p->x` is itself an object whose lifetime depends on `*p`, and then `transform2()`, which is effectively *unaware* of the temporal relationship between its arguments, passes `val` onwards to some sink function, without taking care to keep `*p` alive. And, given its own scope, how would it know it should?

Move semantics are just one of a set of features that can be easily abused, and needs to be handled with care. Then again, that's part of the essential charm of C++: it requires attention to details. In return for that added responsibility, it gives you more control—or is it the other way around?

Comment: Once the move construction takes place, anything inside p whether a POD or an object would be invalid, so I'm not sure I got the gist of your extended example. Regarding the philosophical part, I feel the demonstrated bug could be a common gotcha, so I hoped there is a more robust way to avoid it. Given that there isn't one currently, I hope one could be added to std.

Comment: @Danra The point is that even if you had taken care to fetch `p->x` _prior_ to issuing the call, then, depending on what `p->x` _is_, you might still encounter bugs. It just went to show that there's a lot of details that need to be taken into consideration to write correct C++. I'd say that `std::move()` isn't a "do-always" kind of thing. Rather, it should be used when _necessary_ to achieve correctness (first), then performance. It's an inherently dangerous tool, since it allows you to retain access to invalid objects.

Comment: I see your point now. But copying/moving p->x beforehand, and still having its lifetime depend on *p, sounds to me like you've designed something wrong :) However, copying p->x into a parameter of a function call, at the same time as you're moving p itself into another parameter of the function call, sounds like it should work - or at least looks like it should, in a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

ammm... not much of an answer but a suggestion - why pass the ownership of the `unique_ptr` in the first place? it seems that `transformXXX` play with the integer value, why does memory management has to play a part here?

pass the `unique_ptr` by reference :

```
unique_ptr<C>& transform1(unique_ptr<C>& p) {
    return transform2(p, p->x); // 
}

unique_ptr<C>& transform2(unique_ptr<C> p&, int val) {
    p->x *= val;
    return p;
}
```

pass ownership **outside** these functions. create specific functions which this is their job. seperate algebric logic from memory management.

Comment: Indeed, it's a simplified example. In my real case I do need to transfer ownership.

Comment: your functions shouldn't do more that one good thing. passing owneship and doing math is a job for two functions, not one.

Comment: @DavidHaim, if what you are saying would be true, there would be no need for any ownership semantics within any smart pointer.

Comment: @SergeyA no, I'm saying that there should be functions which pass memory, and functions that do math, not both.

Comment: This should just pass a non-owning raw pointer (or an `observer_ptr`). If you are not touching ownership, you shouldn't care what owns the object.