# store newed Objects in smart pointers in standalone statement

Tags: c++, function, effective-c++

I was going through [Item 17](https://flylib.com/books/en/2.887.1.30/1/) of Effective C++ 3rd Edition.

In that it is mentioned that order in which arguments are executed for a function call:

```
processWidget(std::tr1::shared_ptr<Widget> pw(new Widget), priority());
```

can be:

1) Execute "new Widget"
2) calling priority 
3) Call tr1::shared_ptr c'tor.

Is this really the case in latest C++ compilers. I mean, i strongly feel that compiler should call step 1 and 3 one after the other not like above case since its one single argument. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.
Also, if someone asked this question, you can redirect it to that page since i didn't find any in SO.

Comment: It's not the case in C++17.

Comment: Good reading: [Why doesn't c++ have a specified order for evaluating function arguements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38764793/why-doesnt-c-have-a-specified-order-for-evaluating-function-arguements)

Comment: Took me longer than it should have to track this one down. [What are the evaluation order guarantees introduced by C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587/what-are-the-evaluation-order-guarantees-introduced-by-c17)

Comment: @PasserBy so can i say there will be no memory leak then? or I don't have to add standalone statement before calling a function as mention in my attached link?

Comment: Sidenote: make this all irrelevant [with `std::make_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared).

Comment: It's not about the latest compilers but rather that you enable C++17. If you use the newest compiler and don't set it to compile in C++17, there's no such guarantee.

Comment: Yes. But the semantics is often misunderstood. Note also that `std::make_shared` does more than prevent memory leaks pre-C++17, it lumps allocations together, which isn't always the best option.